# SQL SELECT DATETIME CLOSEST TO @to OR USE @to

Tags: sql, group-by, case, default-value

Assuming I have a table with Id, Value, TimeStamp.
(timestamp is datetime, but i'm writing it in seudo-time, so both americans and others understand it ;-) )

| ID | Value | TimeStamp |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 101 | 10 | '1-feb-2020' |
| 101 | 20 | '28-feb-2020' |
| 202 | 5 | '15-feb-2020' |
| 202 | 15 | '20-feb-2020' |
| 303 | 50 | '10-feb-2020' |
| 303 | 60 | '1-mar-2020' |

I want to select the first record after a certain timestamp (@to) and if none can be found, default to @to (or mayby just null), grouped by Id.

The bigger picture where this issue comes from, is that I need to find the first and last [Value] for each given timeinterval (Hour, Day, Month, Year) between @from and @to, AND the first [Value] before @from and after @to.

I've tried a few variations of:

```
DECLARE @to DateTime = '28-feb-2020'

SELECT Id
    MIN( TimeStamp ) FirstTimeStampAfterToOrDefault
 FROM MyTable
 WHERE Id IN ( 101,202, 303 )
 AND TimeStamp  >= @to
 GROUP BY Id
```

BUT I can't get it to Default to @to if there isn't any TimeStamps higher than @to

Which means that I don't get any results back from the query..

The result I'm looking for is:

| Id | FirstTimeStampAfterToOrDefault |
| --- | --- |
| 101 | '28-feb-2020' (Equal to @to) |
| 202 | '28-feb-2020' (defeaulted to @to) |
| 303 | '1-mar-2020' (there was a timestamp higher than) |

Comment: *but i'm writing it in seudo-time, so both americans and others understand it* - no need to worry about cultures just use ISO YYYYMMDD which is unambiguous.

Comment: Numerous options exist depending on the specific product you're using such as a case expression, isnull, coalesce, nullif....

Answer (score 0):

What you want is the greatest value among

- the highest value
- @to

so:

```
DECLARE @to DateTime = '28-feb-2020'

SELECT Id
    greatest( MAX( TimeStamp ), @to) FirstTimeStampAfterToOrDefault
 FROM MyTable
 WHERE Id IN ( 101,202, 303 )
 GROUP BY Id
```

[db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/8x9250ZG)

Answer (score 0):

One way is moving the condition to conditional aggregation in SELECT

```
SELECT Id
    MIN(case when TimeStamp > @to then TimeStamp else @to end) FirstTimeStampAfterToOrDefault
 FROM MyTable
 WHERE Id IN ( 101,202, 303 )
 GROUP BY Id
```

Note it has a performance penalty of not using index on TimeStamp if present.